# Is there any way to prevent mobile mail clients from automatically forcing emails into "mobile-friendly" format?

Tags: html, css, email, mobile, html-email

I have an email design that actually looks good on mobile, web, and desktop mail clients. The problem is when some mobile clients, like Gmail on Android, automatically decide to reformat the email to make it more mobile friendly. They mutilate the design and the email looks horrible. Then you click on the button to show the original version and it looks fine.

Is there a way to signal to mobile mail clients not to automatically reformat an e-mail?

Comment: have you tried using an inliner? like http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php

Comment: I did try an inliner but it didn't really make much difference. The autofit/autosizing that the Gmail app performs breaks the layout regardless. It wouldn't be an issue if it was obvious to turn off, but the option is buried in a settings menu that I feel most users would never think to bother with.

Comment: Ahh bummer. I've always started with https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template as a skeleton and customized everything from that. Run it thru Zurb or Premailer and I've never had any issues with mobile or desktop rendering

Comment: @s0rfi949 I found a solution that worked for me. I posted an answer below if you are interested.

Comment: cool thanks, if you post your code it will be easier to find an answer too for next time

Answer (score 1):

So I found that if you put max and min sizes on your whole layout, the Gmail app respects that. For example, on my table I put max-width, max-height, min-width, min-height, width, and height CSS properties, as well as setting the width and height html properties. I repeated this for all of the child elements, down to the div and img tags. This at least passed the Gmail for Android test.

Comment: this works for all clients that support media queries (ios and android default mail clients, apple mail, outlook.com)